# How to print several markers google map api 0.5.7 Flutter

Tags: google-maps, mobile, google-maps-api-3, flutter

I am trying to use google map api last version (0.5.7) but on my map there is only one marker that is printed but there are many markes on the database and it was working well before I tried to put the last version. Does someone know how to print many markers ? I put arrow where the markers are used.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';

import 'package:location/location.dart';

import 'package:geoflutterfire/geoflutterfire.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:rxdart/rxdart.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

import 'customs_icons_icons.dart';
import 'Dialogs.dart';
import 'Metro.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        home: Scaffold(
          body: FireMap(),
        ));
  }
}

class FireMap extends StatefulWidget {
  State createState() => FireMapState();
}

class FireMapState extends State<FireMap> {
  GoogleMapController mapController;
  Location location = new Location();
  Dialogs dialogs = new Dialogs();
  Firestore firestore = Firestore.instance;
  Geoflutterfire geo = Geoflutterfire();

  BehaviorSubject<double> radius = BehaviorSubject(seedValue: 100.0);
  Stream<dynamic> query;

  StreamSubscription subscription;`enter code here`

  Map<MarkerId, Marker> markers = <MarkerId, Marker>{};
  MarkerId selectedMarker;
  int _markerIdCounter = 1;

  build(context) {
    return Stack(children: [
      GoogleMap(
        initialCameraPosition:
            CameraPosition(target: LatLng(45.758077, 4.833316), zoom: 15),
        onMapCreated: _onMapCreated,
        myLocationEnabled: true,
        mapType: MapType.normal,
        compassEnabled: true,
        markers: Set<Marker>.of(markers.values),<---
      ),
      Positioned(
        bottom: 20,
        right: 20,
        child: Container(
          height: 80.0,
          width: 80.0,
          child: FittedBox(
            child: FloatingActionButton(
              child: Icon(CustomsIcons.ticket, color: Colors.black),
              backgroundColor: Colors.pink[200],
              onPressed: () => dialogs.information(
                  context, 'Confirmer ?', 'description', addGeoPoint),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ]);
  }

  _onMapCreated(GoogleMapController controller) {
    _startQuery();
   setState(
      () {
        mapController = controller;
      },
    );
  }


  void _updateMarkers(List<DocumentSnapshot> documentList) { <---
    final String markerIdVal = 'marker_id_$_markerIdCounter';
    _markerIdCounter++;
    final MarkerId markerId = MarkerId(markerIdVal);
    print(documentList);
    markers.clear();
    documentList.forEach(
      (DocumentSnapshot document) {
        GeoPoint pos = document.data['position']['geopoint'];
        var marker = Marker(
            markerId: markerId,
            position: LatLng(pos.latitude, pos.longitude),
            icon: BitmapDescriptor.fromAsset('assets/ticket_point.png'),
            infoWindow:
                InfoWindow(title: 'Ici à :', snippet: document.data['time']));
        setState(() {
          markers[markerId] = marker;
        });
      },
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works ! I just moved markerIDcounter in "(DocumentSnapshot document)" and all the markers appears

Answer (score -1):

I do it like this way

```
class _MapActivityState extends State<MapActivity> {
  GoogleMapController _controller;
  static LatLng _center = LatLng(0.0, 0.0);
  Position currentLocation;
  Set<Marker> _markers = {};

  void _onMapCreated(GoogleMapController controller) {
    setState(() {
      _controller = controller;
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    setState(() {
      getUserLocation();
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Home"),
      ),
      body: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          GoogleMap(
            onMapCreated: _onMapCreated,
            initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(target: _center, zoom: 15),
            markers: _markers,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
 getUserLocation() async {
    currentLocation = await locateUser();
    setState(() {
      for (int i = 0; i < myresponse.data.length; i++) {
        _markers.add(Marker(
            markerId: MarkerId(myresponse[i].userId),
            position: LatLng(double.parse(myresponse[i].latitude),
                double.parse(myresponse[i].longitude)),
            icon: myresponse[i].capacity.contains("7.2")
                ? BitmapDescriptor.fromAsset(
                    'assets/charger_location.png',
                  )
                : BitmapDescriptor.fromAsset(
                    'assets/marker_green.png',
                  ),
            infoWindow: InfoWindow(
                title: myresponse[i].stationName,
                snippet: myresponse[i].contactPerson,
                onTap: () => _onTap(myresponse[i]))));
      }
    });
 }
}
```